# Grails Filter to Detect Session Timeouts

Tags: grails, filter

Is there any support for filters in `Grails` ? 
I need a filter to detect `http session timeouts` and direct the user to an appropriate page asking them to login again. Does the spring security core plugin already provide this functionality? 
I can't find any reliable information on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unsure if it is of use : (apache-shiro) - https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener this may help you find relevant information for spring security + this https://github.com/vahidhedayati/customshiro

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any support for filters in Grails?

Yes.  You can register servlet filters in web.xml as per usual Java servlet apps but more common is to use Grails' own filter support which is documented at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters.

```
class SessionTimeoutFilters {
    def filters = {
        all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            // impose your logic here
        } 
    }
}
```